# Public music database that expose APIs to get most popular songs?

Tags: data-request, api, music

I know there are a lot of [public music databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_music_databases), but I'm not able to find one that expose APIs to get most popular/played/listened songs, for example I checked last.fm APIs and the only method to search songs that I found is [getTracks](http://www.last.fm/api/show/library.getTracks) that retrieves

> paginated list of all the tracks in a user's library

So my question is: Is there any music database that expose APIs to get most popular/played/listened songs/tracks?

Comment: spotify API? https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/

Comment: also see this from 2017 https://stackoverflow.com/q/42130591/2327328